# How does this splice code work in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming so sorry if this is a stupid question.

In the following code I know that "March" is at index 1. With spice we are saying start at index 1, remove 0 (none) and add Feb. When we add feb, does it push march across?

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'March', 'April', 'June'];
months.splice(1, 0, 'Feb');
console.log(months);
```

Comment: Why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

The splice function deletes and/or inserts an element at a specific position. https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

I don't understand your question. March will remain in the array but will be pushed one index further